# PostgreSQL To get most popular product?

Tags: postgresql

What is the most popular product purchased in north east?

```
Product(product_id, p_description)
Customer(cusid,fname,lname,state,zipcode)
Purchase(purchase_id,cusid,product_id,purchasetimestamp,quantity ,price)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT        * 
FROM          product 
WHERE         productid 
IN (
  SELECT      TOP 1 
              productid 
  FROM        purchase 
  WHERE       customerid 
  IN (
    SELECT    customerid 
    FROM      customer 
    WHERE     zip 
    IN ()
  GROUP BY    productid 
  ORDER BY    count(productid) DESC
)
```

Comment: Confused??

Comment: I'm more confused about what your question is asking.

Comment: @Smile: When you say "confused" are you suggesting that this doesn't work? Or that it works, but you don't understand _how_ it works?

Comment: @Smile: Also, I attempted to clean up the formatting so it's at least easier to read here on Stack Overflow. In doing so, however, it became apparent that there is a mistake in your code. You're missing at least one closing parenthesis, and have an empty `WHERE … IN()` without a nested query. Can you clarify what you're attempting to do here, and ensure that your SQL statement is working?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT product. product_id, 
SUM (purchase. purchasetimestamp)
FROM purchase
JOIN product ON product. product_id = purchase. product_id 
GROUP BY product. product_id
ORDER BY SUM DESC;
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to limit the results to the Northeast. The regional limit seems to be a key part of the question (acknowledging that the question isn't terribly clear).